# Open ASP web application with parameter in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to correctly setup ASP.Net web application to receive parameter from URL? And how to read this parameter in C#?
I want call my application in this way: ...Default.aspx?@param1=XXX

XXX value must be variable, different users will call it with different values.

Comment: ASP,  ASP.Net or ASP.Net Core?

Comment: In ASP.Net web.

Comment: What do you mean by "ASP.NET Web"? Is it Web Forms? MVC? Web Pages? Raw handlers? You need to clearly describe the framework you plan to use, because they all work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Easy

in Routeconfig set a new route

```
         routes.MapRoute(
          name: "testpass",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{par}",
          defaults: new { controller = "YourControler", action = "parameter", par = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

and the controller set

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult parameter(string par)
    {
        return Json(new { response = par }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

to call it

```
https://localhost:44307/YourControler/parameter/?par=123
```